# Changing 'memory_limit', 'post_max_size', and 'upload_max_filesize' in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, upload, php

I know there are a lot of questions on here about this, but most of them seem to be from people who don't know that '`memory_limit`', '`post_max_size`', and '`upload_max_filesize`' are `PHP_INI_PERDIR` (i.e. they can't be changed using `ini_set()`). I already learned that the hard way.

However, everything indicates that I should be able to change them using a .htaccess file—everything, that is, except my actual experience.

Here are the contents of my .htaccess file:

```
# Allow large file uploads
php_value memory_limit 4294967296
php_value post_max_size 1073741824
php_value upload_max_filesize 524288000
```

I've tried a number of different combinations, but none of them seem to have any effect on anything. I know I've gotta be missing something, but I can't for the life of me figure out what that something is.

P.S. I'm running PHP 5.2.4 locally on Mac OS X 10.4 from entropy.ch.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you unable to upload files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to permit those settings to be changed in a .htaccess file. For that, you need `AllowOverride Options` or `AllowOverride All` in a relevant section your httpd.conf file (in a `<Directory>` block for that directory or a parent thereof).

Note also this will only work if you're using Apache and `mod_php5` (i.e., no CGI/FastCGI/whatever).

See also [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php).

Comment: Ah, that was precisely it. I'd assumed I was already set up for that. (You know what happens, etc.)

Boy did it take a lot of searching and trial and error just to find the right .conf file and the right server to restart....

But thank you!